# mxml use .swc library file to addChild components to panel/canvas/etc and run code for game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

I am using flash builder to build a flex project, and I am just getting into `mxml`. I have a flash game that I made in Flash Professional CC - I published an `swc` file from Flash CC - all of the symbols are exported in 1st frame, and exported for actionscript (in Symbol Properties) - They reside in the same folder as the `swc` file.

In Flash Builder 4.6 - I added the `swc` file to the library path so that I could access the symbols. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <!-- <s:VGroup>
        <s:TextArea id="textArea" width="300" height="300"/>
        <s:Button label="Connect" click="onConnectClick()"/>
        <s:Button label="Send" click="onSendClick()"/>
        <s:Button label="Disconnect" click="onDisconnectClick()"/>
    </s:VGroup> -->
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import Avatar;
            import Enemy;

            import flash.display.*;

            import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
            import com.hurlant.util.der.Integer;

            import io.socket.flash.ISocketIOTransport;
            import io.socket.flash.ISocketIOTransportFactory;
            import io.socket.flash.SocketIOErrorEvent;
            import io.socket.flash.SocketIOEvent;
            import io.socket.flash.SocketIOTransportFactory;
            import io.socket.flash.WebsocketTransport;
            import io.socket.flash.XhrPollingTransport;

            import flash.utils.Timer;
            import flash.events.TimerEvent;

            import flash.system.Security;

            private var _socketIOTransportFactory:ISocketIOTransportFactory = new SocketIOTransportFactory();
            private var _ioSocket:ISocketIOTransport;

            Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://localhost:10843");

            private function onConnectClick():void
            {
                _ioSocket = _socketIOTransportFactory.createSocketIOTransport(XhrPollingTransport.TRANSPORT_TYPE, "localhost:8000/socket.io", this);
                _ioSocket.addEventListener(SocketIOEvent.CONNECT, onSocketConnected);
                _ioSocket.addEventListener(SocketIOEvent.DISCONNECT, onSocketDisconnected);
                _ioSocket.addEventListener(SocketIOEvent.MESSAGE, onSocketMessage);
                _ioSocket.addEventListener(SocketIOErrorEvent.CONNECTION_FAULT, onSocketConnectionFault);
                _ioSocket.addEventListener(SocketIOErrorEvent.SECURITY_FAULT, onSocketSecurityFault);
                _ioSocket.connect();
            }

            private function onSocketConnectionFault(event:SocketIOErrorEvent):void
            {
                trace(event.type + ":" + event.text);
            }

            private function onSocketSecurityFault(event:SocketIOErrorEvent):void
            {
                trace(event.type + ":" + event.text);
            }

            private function onDisconnectClick():void
            {
                _ioSocket.disconnect();
            }

            private function onSocketMessage(event:SocketIOEvent):void
            {
                if (event.message is String)
                {
                    trace(String(event.message));
                }
                else
                {
                    trace(com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.encode(event.message));
                }
            }

            private function onSendClick():void
            {
                _ioSocket.send({type: "chatMessage", data: "Привет!!!"});
                _ioSocket.send({type: "chatMessage", data: "Delirium tremens"});
                _ioSocket.send("HELLO!!!");
            }

            private function onSocketConnected(event:SocketIOEvent):void
            {
                //logMessage("Connected" + event.target);
                trace("connected");
            }

            private function onSocketDisconnected(event:SocketIOEvent):void
            {
                //logMessage("Disconnected" + event.target);
                trace("disconnected");
            }

            /*private function logMessage(message:String):void
            {
                textArea.text = textArea.text + message + "\n";
            }*/         

            public function init():void {

                var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy();
                var avatar:Avatar = new Avatar();
                var gameTimer:Timer;    

                myGroup.addChild(enemy);
                myGroup.addChild(avatar);   

                avatar.x = mouseX;
                avatar.y = mouseY;

                gameTimer = new Timer( 25 );
                gameTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick );
                gameTimer.start();

                function onTick( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void 
                {
                    enemy.moveDownABit();
                    avatar.x = mouseX;
                    avatar.y = mouseY;
                    var score:int;

                    if ( avatar.hitTestObject( enemy ) ) 
                    {
                        score = gameTimer.currentCount;
                        gameTimer.stop();
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Group id="myGroup" width="400" height="300" initialize="init();"/>
</s:Application>
```

I have no errors, but it comes up as a blank page (it is a game where there is an avatar and an enemy - and the avatar tries to avoid the enemy as it moves down the screen).

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to embed the `swf` file for the game too?

Also - you can ignore all of the socket stuff - that all works fine (I have already tested it, but I am trying to integrate [socket.io-flash](https://github.com/sinnus/socket.io-flash) with my game). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try embedding your SWF file like this:

```
[Embed(source="foo.swf")]
[Bindable]
public var game:Class;
```

You typically embed a Flex application when you do not require the embedding application to interact with the embedded application. If the embedded application requires interactivity with the embedded application, you might consider implementing it as a custom component, rather than as a separate application.

[Edited]

Otherwise do:

```
[Bindable]
public var loadedSM:SystemManager;

// Initialize variables with information from
// the loaded application.
private function initNestedAppProps():void {
     loadedSM = SystemManager(myLoader.content);
}

.
.
.

<mx:SWFLoader id="myLoader" width="100%" height="100%"
source="foo.swf"
creationComplete="initNestedAppProps();"/>
```

Im not 100% sure this is what you are looking for, and this solution would be a bugger to adapt.
Sorry if i couldnt help

Comment: thanks! the thing is - i do want to integrate the socket stuff with the embedded swf - How do I implement as a custom component?

Comment: I just read this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb53b71817412e76383d7f-8000.html - which lead me to this - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-120529f3137a1e031d6-7ffe.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-120529f3137a1e031d6-7ffa - looks like I want an ActionScript skinnable component - however when I go to add the component (called AvoiderGame.as) it says..."avoider.swc already exists." - I know why this is happening, I already have the avoider.swc in my library paths - it is somehow being implemented (but not used).

Comment: I also have a copy of AvoiderGame.as in my `bin-debug` folder but I didn't put it there - I think it knows that AvoiderGame.as wants to be something.

Comment: jaja, " I think it knows that AvoiderGame.as wants to be something", That made me laugh ^-^

Comment: Take a look at my edit, if you dont understand it i can add some examples of how to use it

Comment: glad I made u laugh lol - one question - where is `myLoader` coming from? it says - Access of undefined property - I know what this means - but where is myLoader instantiated?

Comment: myLoader is the id of the SWFLoader in the mxml

Comment: i think i got it - added `var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();` to `initNestedAppProps` function

Comment: oh i get it...I didnt put the mx script in yet

Comment: thanks so much! got it working! can i ask u questions if i ever have any? wats ur email?

Comment: Okay, so now if you wanted to access something in your game, for example imagine your game had a label called lbl and you wanted to change the text of that label, you would use this:
`loadedSM.application["lbl"].text = "foo";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53974/discussion-between-gary-perry-and-ewizard).

Comment: ahhhh wonderful - i will need to do that with the sockets right?

Comment: this is a problem I am having right now - the only way i could find to contact you was through this comment and '@' symbol...is there an easier way to message people on stackoverflow? take a look at this when you get a chance...I have isolated the problem but I have no idea what is going on...I started using the starling flash library if you have any experience with that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784027/starling-library-when-i-try-and-change-cursor-to-image-it-doesnt-work-and

Comment: I am trying to rebuild the flash game I made using starling - problem is unrelated to sockets...and I imagine I am just doing something stupid for which I don't know any better.

Comment: Hey! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784027/starling-library-when-i-try-and-change-cursor-to-image-it-doesnt-work-and - i just figured out the conflict for why the sprite dissapears...but i still need help with the cursor - the image for the cursor isnt changing. let me edit the question to reflect what i did real quick.